# Rename axis name in overlapping histogram

Tags: sas

I'm doing overlapping histograms and am trying to rename the horizontal axis. How do I do this? My code currently looks like this:

```
proc sgplot data=gender2;
title "Overlapping full salary by gender";
histogram FSAL /
LEGENDLABEL= "Women";
histogram MSAL /transparency=0.5 LEGENDLABEL= "Men";
run;
```

And I want the x-axis to say "Salary" instead of "FSAL"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the XAXIS statement to modify the label of the X Axis.

```
proc sgplot data=gender2;
title "Overlapping full salary by gender";
histogram FSAL /
LEGENDLABEL= "Women";
histogram MSAL /transparency=0.5 LEGENDLABEL= "Men";
xaxis label="Salary";
run;
```

Or, add the label "Salary" to the `FSAL` varaible in the `gender2` dataset.